# Mysql Advanced Selecting

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this mysql statement. I want it to select all the friends of my friends that I'm not friends with. Right now, this just selects all of my friends' friends, even if I'm a friend with that person. The result is something like this:

My Friends- Bob, Joe. Suggested Friends - Jim, Jon, Bob

Bob should not be on the suggested friends list because he's on my list. Could I do this with an advanced mysql statement, or do I need to do something else? Thanks!

My current sql code:

```
SELECT * FROM friendlist WHERE addby='$user'
```

Full Code:

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$find = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM friendlist WHERE addby='$user'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find)){
$friend = $row['username'];
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM friendlist WHERE addby='$friend'");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){

    if(!isset($list)){
        $list = "";
    }
    $list .= "<a href='profile.php?u=" . $row2['username'] . "'>" .     $row2['username'] . "</a><br>";                 
}
echo "<a href='profile.php?u=" . $row['username'] . "'>" . $row['username'] . "</a>   <br>";
}


echo $list;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* give you the results you're looking for, if I'm understanding what you want and your table structure correctly.  More details about your structure may help if this doesn't do it for you.

```
SELECT * FROM friendlist WHERE addby = '$friend' AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM friendlist WHERE addby = '$user');
```

You may need to change the 'id' column to whatever works in your table (the primary key, presumably).  This works by filtering out the results of the select subquery which should return all of the users friend list, again assuming I understand your table structure.